# Why does the free fermionic 2-point correlation matrix $C_{ij}=\langle c^{\dagger}_i c_j\rangle$ have eigenvalues equal to either $0$ or $1$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information

Consider a system of free fermions with Hamiltonian
$$
H = \sum_{ij} t_{ij}c^{\dagger}_ic_j\quad \longrightarrow \quad H = \sum_k E_k d^{\dagger}_kd_k, 
$$
with $t_{ij}$ hermitian. An eigenstate  $|\psi \rangle$ of $H$ is given by acting on $|0\rangle$ with $d^{\dagger}$s as usual:
$$
|\psi^{N_p}\rangle = \prod_{a \in N_p} d_a | 0 \rangle \quad \text{where} \quad d_a = \sum_i\phi^a_ic_i,
$$
where the set $\{\phi^a\}$ are the eigenvectors of $t_{ij}$. Its 2-point correlator matrix $C$ given by
$$
C_{ij} = \langle \psi | c^{\dagger}_i c_j |\psi\rangle \equiv \langle c^{\dagger}_i c_j \rangle_{\psi}= \sum_k\overline{\phi_i^{k}}\phi^k_j\langle d^{\dagger}_kd_k\rangle_{\psi}=  \sum_k\overline{\phi_i^{k}}\phi^k_j \delta_{k\in \psi}=  \sum_{k\in \psi}\overline{\phi_i^{k}}\phi^k_j.
$$
**Why are the eigenvalues of $C$ all either $0$ or $1$**?

When I try to find them I run into:
$$
\sum_j C_{ij} \xi^n_j = \Xi^n \xi^n_i \implies \sum_j \sum_{k\in \psi}\overline{\phi_i^{k}}\phi^k_j \xi^n_j = \Xi^n \xi^n_i,\tag{1}
$$
and can’t go any further. I know that $\{\phi^n\}$ satisfy the usual properties of the eigenvectors of a hermitian matrix, namely
$$
\sum_{k}\overline{\phi_i^{k}}\phi^k_j =\delta_{ij} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{i}\overline{\phi_i^{k}}\phi^p_i = \delta^{kp},
$$
but I cant use the first one in (1) as $k$ doesn’t run through all its values, i.e. it depends on $\psi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to use that the $\phi_i^k$ form a unitary matrix $U\equiv U_{ij}$.

Then, your formula
$$
C_{ij} = \sum_k\overline{\phi_i^{k}}\phi^k_j\langle d^{\dagger}_kd_k\rangle_{\psi}
$$
reads
$$ C = UD U^\dagger
$$
(with $D$ a real diagonal matrix with entries $0$ and $1$), and thus $C$ and $D$ have the same spectrum (the spectrum is invariant under conjugation with $U$).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. (For future learners: defining $U_{ij} = \phi_i^j$ would imply that if $U$ is unitary then $U^{\dagger}U=1$ and in terms of $\phi$’s, $(U^{\dagger})_{ij}U_{jk}=\overline{\phi^j_i}\phi^j_k = \delta_{ik}$ which indeed works out.)

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian Comment on your edit: The point is not really that U diagonalized C - the point is that *any* two matrices related by conjugation with U have the same spectrum.